# Error opening PowerPoint presentation: Method 'Open' of object 'Presentations' failed

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to open another PowerPoint presentation to copy the two slides in it to the end of my current presentation.

I used `Presentations.Open (ppt_SourceFile)` to open the presentation, however, it gave me an error:

> Run-time error '-2147467259(80004005)': Method 'Open' of object 'Presentations' failed.

```vb
Sub copyFromPPT()
Dim slideCount As Integer
Dim sourcePath as string, ppt_SourceFile As String, pptSource As String, thisPresentation As String

    'Copy and paste the pages at the end
    thisPresentation = ActivePresentation.Name
    slideCount = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    
    'Open ppt file
    sourcePath = ActivePresentation.Path
    ppt_SourceFile = sourcePath & "\CFTC Reg Reporting*.pptx"
    
    Presentations.Open (ppt_SourceFile)
    pptSource = ActivePresentation.Name
    
    'Copy the 1st slide of source ppt to end of this slide
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Copy
    Presentations(thisPresentation).Slides.paste
    slideCount = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    
    'Copy the 2nd slide of source ppt to end of this slide
    Presentations(pptSource).Slides(2).Copy
    Presentations(thisPresentation).Slides.paste
    
    'Close source ppt file
    Presentations(pptSource).Close
    ActivePresentation.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the name of your ppt literally `CFTC Reg Reporting*.pptx`, or is that `*` intended to be a wildcard?

Comment: @Tim Williams *is supposed to be a wildcard, because the name of the source ppt has a date suffix to it.

Comment: You need to figure out the specific file name you want to open, can't use wildcards to provide a single filename, what happens when two files match the wildcard pattern?

Comment: @ Mathieu Guindon There would only be one file with the name starting with "CFTC Reg Reporting"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's only one matching file in the folder you can do something like this:

```vb
Sub copyFromPPT()
    Dim thisPres As Presentation, sourcePres As Presentation, f
    Dim sourcePath As String

    Set thisPres = ActivePresentation
    
    sourcePath = thisPres.Path & "\"
    f = Dir(sourcePath & "CFTC Reg Reporting*.pptx") 'see if there's a file...
    If Len(f) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No matching file found", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set sourcePres = Presentations.Open(sourcePath & f) 'Open ppt file and get a reference
    
    sourcePres.Slides(1).Copy
    thisPres.Slides.Paste     'you can add a paste position here, or leave blank to paste to the end...
    sourcePres.Slides(2).Copy
    thisPres.Slides.Paste
    
    sourcePres.Close
    thisPres.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! this solve my problem! But I have another question, why can I open an Excel file using my previous code without any issue? I also used the wildcard * because it also has a date suffix.

Comment: I used this line to open an excel file in order to copy some data and paste to ppt. It is able to open the excel file without any issue:                                                    
       Workbooks.Open sourcePath & "\RD_Details_Data" & "*.csv"

Comment: Opening a file in Excel with `*` as a wildcard doesn't work for me.